# python+raspberry pi gpio invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax, gpio

i am doing an internship and i need to come up with a Raspberry Pi that will have a clicker to add subtract 1 and reset to 0 for how many days accident free for the company and the site, here is the code i have but im getting an Invalid Syntax at the While True part, i have no experience in coding before this so any help would be great thanks!

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.Setup (17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.Setup (18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.Setup (21, GPIO.IN, Pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.Setup (22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup (23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.Setup (24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN
    while True:
        Try:
        If(GPIO.input(17)== 1):
            writeTexts(+1,-370,55)
            writeTexts(today +difference1,-100,-200)
        If(GPIO.input(18)== 1):
            WriteTexts(-1,-370,55)
        If(GPIO.input(21)== 1):
            writeTexts(0,-370,55)
        If(GPIO.Input(22)==1):
            writeTexts(+1,280,55)
        If(GPIO.input(23)== 1):
            writeTexts(-1,280,55)
            writeTexts(today +difference1,550,-200)
        If(GPIO.input(24)==1):
            writeTexts(0,280,55)
            sleep(.01)
    except KeyboardInterrupt
        exit()
GPIO.Cleanup ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have imported `GPIO,time` and any modules at the top of your code:

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.Setup (17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.Setup (18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.Setup (21, GPIO.IN, Pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.Setup (22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup (23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.Setup (24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN) 

while True:
    try:
        if GPIO.input(17) == 1: # all `if` should be lowercase and the `try` 
            writeTexts(+1,-370,55) # don't need `()` in if statements.
            writeTexts(today + difference1,-100,-200)
        if GPIO.input(18) == 1:
            WriteTexts(-1,-370,55)
        if GPIO.input(21) == 1:
            writeTexts(0,-370,55)
        if GPIO.Input(22) == 1:
            writeTexts(+1,280,55)
        if GPIO.input(23) == 1:
            writeTexts(-1,280,55)
            writeTexts(today + difference1,550,-200)
        if GPIO.input(24) == 1:
            writeTexts(0,280,55)
            sleep(.01)
    except KeyboardInterrupt: # missing `:`
        exit()

GPIO.Cleanup ()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a final closing `)` on the line just before `while True`:

```
GPIO.Setup (24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN
```

Additionally, `Try` and `If` should be lowercase.

Comment: And the `while` and `try` are indented too much. And the `if`s don’t need parentheses. And there’s other PEP 8 violations.